# Kivy designer doesn't get found in macOS python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

The problem is that I have Kivy on my Mac and I've installed Kivy Designer, but I don't know how can I open Kivy Designer. I have put 'kivy-designer' in the terminal and nothing happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not run kivy-designer this way. In [documentation](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer#installation) write that you need type `python -m designer` from folder where you clone repository.